# explicit call of templated overloaded operator

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading

i have a class with a overladed operators.

```
class sout {
public:
  template<typename T>
  friend inline sout& operator&(sout&, T&);

  friend inline sout& operator&(sout&, std::string&);
};
```

now if i use the templated operator& inside the the sting.operator& i get an error:

code:

```
sout& operator&(sout& s, std::string& str) {
  uint16_t ts = static_cast<uint16_t>(str.size());  // this is ok
  s & ts; // is also ok

  s & static_cast<uint16_t>(str.size());  // but this is wrong

  // ...
  return s;
}
```

error:

```
Error:C2679: binary '&' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'uint16_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
could be 'sout &operator &<uint16_t>(sout &,T &)'
with
[
    T=uint16_t
]
or       'sout &operator &(sout &,std::string &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(sout, uint16_t)'
```

than i tried to use the explicite operator& template-type by:

```
operator&<uint16_t>(s, ts);  // this also ig ok
```

but if i combine it, i again a error:

```
operator&<uint16_t>(s, static_cast<uint16_t>(str.size())
```

error:

```
'operator &' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'uint16_t' to 'uint16_t &'
```

i also tried reinterpret_cast.

i know operator& is expecting a reference to uint16_t and the size() function is returning a size_t (int) not a reference. is it possible to do that in one line?

Comment: maybe use const reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the value returned by `size()` is a temporary, and temporaries are rvalues; however, your function accepts an *lvalue* reference. The following snippet clarifies the problem:

```
int foo() { return 42; }
void bar(int& i) { i++; } // Parameter is an lvalue reference to non-const

int main()
{
    bar(foo()); // ERROR! Passing an rvalue to bar()
    bar(1729); // ERROR! Passing an rvalue to bar()

    int i = 42;
    bar(i); // OK! Passing an lvalue to bar()
}
```

lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues, unless they are references to `const`.

```
template<typename T>
friend inline sout& operator&(sout&, T const&);
//                                     ^^^^^
```

If your `operator&` is supposed to modify the right hand argument, so that the reference cannot be a reference to `const`, in C++11 you may use rvalue references (this will allow to bind to lvalues as well due to C++11's reference collapsing rules):

```
template<typename T>
friend inline sout& operator&(sout&, T&&);
//                                   ^^^
```

Comment: @itwasntpete: Don't worry, that happens ;)